# Segmentation Fault in array of array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I just started learning C++ and get such error. It passed through compiling but get segmentation fault during run. Could anyone help me with that? I am not sure where the problem is because I am really not familiar with segmentation error. I did check some other post on this topic and did not get it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ThreeSum{

private :
  int *numbers;
  int n;

public:
  ThreeSum();
  ThreeSum(int numbers_in[], int n_in);
  int **threeSumCombinations(){
    int **SumCom;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      for(int j=i+1; i<n; j++){
        for(int k=j+1; j<n; k++){
          if(numbers[i]+numbers[j]+numbers[k]==0){
            SumCom[i][0]=numbers[i];
            SumCom[i][1]=numbers[j];
            SumCom[i][2]=numbers[k];
          }
        }
      }
    };
    return SumCom;
  }
};

ThreeSum::ThreeSum(int numbers_in[], int n_in)
  :numbers(numbers_in), n(n_in){}

int main(){
  int arr[5] = {2,1,0,-1,-2};
  ThreeSum t1(arr,5);
  cout << sizeof(t1.threeSumCombinations()) << endl;//output is 8
  for(int i=0; i<sizeof(t1.threeSumCombinations()); i++){
    cout << t1.threeSumCombinations()[i] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with you should consider carefully when creating classes with dynamic memory. The start would be with `threeSumCombinations()` where you declare `int **SumCom` but **where do you allocate memory for it ???**

Comment: I see a lot of errors. You need to add comments in your code so others can read it.

Comment: First, `sizeof(t1.threeSumCombinations())` is simply the size, in bytes, of a pointer (apparently, you are running on a 64-bit system). It's unrelated to the size, in elements, of an array `threeSumCombinations()` might return. Second, `SimCom` is used but is never initialized.

Comment: -1 for 'I did check some other post on this topic and did not get it'. Phrases like this a a touchstone for 'OK. suckers, feel sorry for me and do my debugging for me because I don't want to do all that hard work'.  Googling 'segmentation fault' gets: 'About 1,060,000 results'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I segmentation fault is an error that occurs when you read memory that you aren't suppose to this. This happens most frequently when using pointers and arrays. Your problem is most likely do to problems with your arrays. I can't tell you were, but just try to make sure you check carefully.

Looking at it, one of the problems seems to be the third 'for loop'. You never check to see if k reaches a limit. Thus, it just keeps going. That's an infinite loop.